# Retrieving data in offline mode

Tags: android, parsing

I have some data on the internet for each specific longitude and latitude. If a user inputs a particular latitude and longitude, the data is downloaded from the web and then used in further calculation. I want to save that data so that the next time the user inputs the same latitude and longitude, It bypasses the web connectivity and proceeds with the existing data.

My Input Class:

```
public class OpTilt extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText latitude, longitude;
Button go;
String data1, data2, link, link1;
double dat1, dat2;
TextView gps;
SharedPreferences dataurl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.optilt);
    initialize();
    go.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loaddata);
    latitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lat);
    longitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lon);
    dataurl = getSharedPreferences("url", 0);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    data1 = longitude.getText().toString();
    data2 = latitude.getText().toString();
    dat1 = Double.parseDouble(data1);
    dat2 = Double.parseDouble(data2);
    link = ("http://www.otilt.com/api.php?lat=" + dat2 + "&lon=" + dat1);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = dataurl.edit();
    editor.putString("key", link);
    editor.commit();
    Intent i = new Intent(OpTilt.this, DataRetrieve.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
}
```

My Parsing Class:

```
public class DataRetrieve extends Activity {

HttpClient client;
String URL, re, element;
JSONObject json, getjson;
int i, j, statusCode;
HttpGet httpget;
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity entity;
InputStream is;
BufferedReader reader;
StringBuilder sb, sb1;
WakeLock w;
SharedPreferences getinput, passjson;
ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    w = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    w.acquire();
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.dataretrieve);
    // Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
    // URL = gotBasket.getString("key");
    getinput = getSharedPreferences("url", 0);
    URL = getinput.getString("key", null);

    Read r = new Read();
    r.execute();

}

public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(DataRetrieve.this);
        pd.setTitle("Processing...");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        re = null;
        is = null;
        json = null;
        try {
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
            response = client.execute(httpget);
            entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            statusCode = -1;
            Log.e("log_tag", "Erro http " + e.toString());
        }
        if (statusCode == 200) {

            try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                        "UTF-8"), 8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                re = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Erro conversão " + e.toString());
            }

        }
        return re;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pd.dismiss();
        try {

            json = new JSONObject(result);
            getjson = json.getJSONObject("Solar");
            String H[] = new String[getjson.length()];
            for (i = 0, j = 1; i < getjson.length(); i++, j++) {
                H[i] = getjson.getString("" + j);

            }

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArray("key1", H);
            Intent f = new Intent(DataRetrieve.this, Calculator.class);
            f.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(f);

        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Erro dados " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    w.release();
    finish();
}

}
```

So, how can I achieve my goal?